# Как объяснить правописание слова “пенсионный”?

Tags: орфография

Пенсионный,почему не ставится мягкий знак после н?

Comment: Вы ведь уже задали такой же вопрос два часа назад. Подождите — и Вам ответят. А этот надо удалить.

Comment: Да, был уже, что там по Фрейду...